# regex until met > without following upper character

Tags: regex

Is it possible to catch values until last `<br>` without `Best` for the following sentence: `@EmailContent<p><p><br><br>Best regards`?

My closest solution `@.+?[\s|\.|>][A-Z]` catches `B` as well.

Comment: Use `@.*?[\s.>](?=[A-Z])`

Comment: Or perhaps use a capturing group `(@[^<>]+(?:<[^<>]+>)+)[A-Z]` https://regex101.com/r/2zJABQ/1

Comment: both are working great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to match the B, you could use a capturing group for the first part without the `[A-Z]`

```
(@.+?[\s.>])[A-Z]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l4IDOr/1)

Or use a more specific pattern using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^` to match any char except listed:

```
(@[^<>]+(?:<[^<>]+>)+)[A-Z]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L3KldM/1)